# What does 血のしょんべん mean?

Tags: words, translation, etymology

I'm trying to figure out what 血のションベン means.  I understand the individual words and literal meaning.  So assuming it doesn't mean "bloods urine", what does this mean?

Perhaps the full sentance is important in this case:
「私が最初に血のションベンを流した」

If you search for this phrase, just as is with the katakana 「ションベン」 you'll find numerous hits online. I seem to always see it associated with 「流す」.

Here's another example, which I found online: 「女性にこんなこと言うのもあれなんやけどな、先生らの時代は　血のションベン（小便）だすまで勉強しろてようゆわれたもんやで」

Comment: Genitive Case: It is the grammatical case that marks a noun as modifying another noun. A genitive construction involves two nouns - the head (modified) noun and the modifier noun. The modifier noun modifies the head noun by expressing some property of it; including, but not necessarily, possession.

Answer (score 3):

血 means blood. しょんべん means pee. So it should be 血尿 meaning bloody urine. I cannot think of other meanings.

Comment: I updated my question with a little more information.

Comment: Is しょんべん a variation of 小便?

Comment: @phoenixheart6 - I think the meanings are similar, but not 100% sure.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 `Is しょんべん a variation of 小便?` - Yes, it's called 転訛. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/153104/m0u/

Comment: @Teno - I've added an additional example of it's use found online.  I get the impression from this one that it's saying something like, "working so hard at something that you are peeing blood".

Answer (score 1):

After reading through pages on Google that use this expression I'm fairly certain that  血のションベン is used to mean "peeing blood".  In context it means something like, "working so hard that you are peeing blood/your urine is bloody".